# renderToString with Redux store renders populated without props (server side)

Tags: react-redux, isomorphic-javascript, server-side-rendering

Although the story id properly prefilled, renderToString() still renders the app without the state being filled in via mapStateToProps().

I use selectors to get data from state.
The problem is, that the props are not being populated. On the client, everything works.

Anyone ideas?
THANKS!

Here's the code for the server side operation:

```
   app.use('*', (req, res) => {

    // // Create a new Redux store instance
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    let middleware = applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware);
    // middleware = compose(middleware,thunkMiddleware)

    const initialState = {};
    const store = createStore(reducers,initialState,middleware);

    store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
    store.close = () => store.dispatch(END);
    const routes = getRoutes(store.getState)

    const tres = res;
    const url = req.originalUrl;
    const urlSplit = url.split('/');

    match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
      if (err) {
        tres.status(500).send(err.message)
      } else if (redirect) {
        tres.redirect(redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
      } else if (props) {

            if(urlSplit[1]==='story'){

              let slug = urlSplit[2];
              store.runSaga(waitAll([[getStoryBySlug,host,slug], [getAbout, host]])).done.then(() => {
                res.end(renderPage(store,props,tres));
              });

            }else{

              store.runSaga(waitAll([[getAbout, host], [getHome, host]])).done.then(() => {
                res.end(renderPage(store,props,tres));
              });

            }

      } else {
        tres.status(404).send('Not Found')
      }
    })

    });

And here are the actual renderPage and renderFullPage functions:

    const renderPage = (store,props,res) => {

    // Render the component to a string
    const html = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterContext {...props}/>
    </Provider>
    )

    let head = Helmet.rewind();
    const preloadedState = fromJS(store.getState());

    return renderFullPage(html, preloadedState, head);

    }

    const renderFullPage = (html, preloadedState, head) => {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        ${head.title.toString()}
        ${head.meta.toString()}
        ${head.link.toString()}
        <script src="https://use.typekit.net/yzi3zgu.js"></script>
        <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

        <link href="/assets/fonts/GillSans/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/assets/vendors/fullpage/jquery.fullPage.css" />
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous" />

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/icons/favicon-inv.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script>
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState)}
        </script>
        <script src="/vendor.js"></script>
        <script src="/main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>

    };
```

Comment: I'm digging this problem too. It's working in browser, but wont work when i wget the page from console.

Comment: Seems, that fetchComponentData only return actions, but no dispatch run.

Comment: Yes, that could be the case. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes. Your dispatch run after you use needs in containers (first children of App component) Your need run, if your action return th hash: {types: ['..._REQUEST', '..._SUCCESS', '..._ERROR'], promises: some_function}. After SUCCESS or ERROR is fired second reducer will change store.